# Trying if ellif in Appium Python

Tags: python, selenium, appium

I need to check if user has already logged into the application. So I have to check for any of the 3 elements below mentioned are present. If anyone of them is present, user is logged in and I need to click sign out button.

The elements are : 
1. sign out button already present(since user is already signed in )
2. Account name

My script is like :

```
 if(wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").is_displayed()):
        wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").click()      
 elif(wd.find_element_by_name("usr_name").is_displayed()):
        wd.find_element_by_name("usr_name").click()
        wd.find_element_by_name("menu_close").click()
        wait("sign out")
        wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").click()
 else:
        print"NOt Signed in"
```

But what happens is my appium is executing the first IF Loop and waiting for the element **sign out** and ends with an error message.

```
An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Where I am doing wrong ? Usually how can I check if an element is present then click it, like that. Please help me.

Comment: What is the complete traceback?

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't the elif be unindented like this:

```
if(wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").is_displayed()):
        wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").click()      
elif(wd.find_element_by_name("usr_name").is_displayed()):
        wd.find_element_by_name("usr_name").click()
        wd.find_element_by_name("menu_close").click()
        wait("sign out")
        wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").click()
else:
        print"NOt Signed in"
```

Comment: Yes. Its already been formatted like the way you have mentioned

Comment: and sidenote, is it supposed to be usr not user? just a question

Comment: ok, I think we need more code to go on, since the problem is the element is not being found it must be an error with the formatting or naming.

Comment: I think you havent understand my question. Its like - to check if that element is present or not, if its present it needs to click that button, else go to the next else statement and check if the button is present, if its not present, go the final else condition and print. But instead of going in between, it gets stuck in the first IF statement and keep on waiting in searching the element and finally shows error.

Comment: its fine. Please help

Comment: could you try:

 if:(args):
    args
 else:
    if(second args):
        args
    else:
        print "error"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wd.implicitly_wait(30)` after each command, so that the appium server waits for next element to be visble

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check an element is present before firing an action just create a method which returns a boolean value based on the isDisplayed property for the element.

Something like this :

```
def IsElementDisplayed():
    try: 
       return wd.find_element_by_name("sign out").is_displayed()
    except:
       return false
```

And call the IsElementDisplayed before each action from the test sript.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no element that has the name "sign out", `find_element_by_name()` is throwing an exception that isn't being handled. One way to solve this is to write a wrapper for searching for elements that includes exception handling. As mentioned in another answer, setting the implicit wait bakes in waiting for elements to be present and repeatedly searches for the element until the timer expires (20s in the code below)

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

wd.implicitly_wait(20)

sign_out = find_element("sign out")
usr_name = find_element("usr_name")

if sign_out is not None and sign_out.is_displayed():
    sign_out.click()
elif usr_name is not None and usr_name.is_displayed():
    usr_name.click()
    menu_close = find_element("menu_close")
    menu_close.click()
    sign_out = find_element("sign out")
    sign_out.click()
else:
    print("Not signed in")

def find_element(self, element_text):
    try:
        element = wd.find_element_by_name(element_text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return None
    return element
```